# Minimize time overhead in trivial recursive virtual function calls

Tags: c++, polymorphism

For sure, virtual function calls produce an runtime overhead.
However, when we have a class member tree, where virtual functions often do nothing but calling another virtual function of its member (and this maybe  recursively), is there a way to minimize the time overhead?

I wrote a short code example demonstrating, what I mean:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual int f(int i)                    { return i+1; }
};

class Derived: public Base {
    Base *another;
  public:
    Derived(Base *a)                        :another(a) { }
    int f(int i) override         { return another->f(i); }
};

int test(Base *x) {
  int ret=0; 
  for (int i=0; i<(1<<30); ++i) ret=x->f(ret);
  return ret;
}

int main() {
  Base x1;
  Derived x2(&x1);
  Derived x3(&x2);
  Derived x4(&x3);
  int r=test(&x1);
  printf("test: %d\n", r);
}
```

Compiled with gcc 5.4.0, optimization option -O3, I get the following run times:

```
test(&x1):  2.444s
test(&x2):  3.280s
test(&x3):  4.088s
test(&x4):  4.852s
```

So, what is the best way to reduce the time overhead? In my special case, templates is not an option.

Comment: Do that even *build* without the compiler complaining? You don't have any inheritance, and passes wrong kind of pointers to the `Derived` constructor and the `test` function.

Comment: your example does not compile, like _at all_ ...

Comment: "... I get the following run times" - no you dont. Your example doesnt even compile. Please post real code

Comment: @Some Sorry, I just corrected some typos in source code. for sure, Derived class is derived from Base. And for sure, I need to pass a pointer to test().

Comment: Do you think that it would ever be possible for you to save enough potential runtime code overhead, so that it actually exceeds the time you spent looking for an answer to this question?

Comment: @Sam In my example a call to test(&x1) is more as twice as fast as test(&x4). The latter is slow only because of calling lots of trivial virtual functions. I hope to get some tip how I can reduce the number of trivial virtual function calls in some way.  In real case, my programs can run for hours. Thus, to answer your question: I hope, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is unlikely, in general, that the overhead of a virtual call will be anything significant compared to the actual workload of the final function.**

---

In case you have profiled, and identified the successive virtual call dispatches as *the* bottleneck, then yes, indeed, it is possible to avoid this. There are actually multiple solutions.

---

The first solution, and most generic, is to resolve the actual function chain once, before the loop, rather than at each step.

In C++11 this will involve using `std::function<...>`. This can be done without compromising customisability too:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual int f(int i)                    { return i+1; }

    virtual std::function<int(int)> f_dispatch() {
        return [this](int i) { return this->Base::f(i); };
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {
    Base* another;
public:
    Derived(Base* a): another(a) { }
    int f(int i) override { return another->f(i); }

    std::function<int(int)> f_dispatch() override {
        return another->f_dispatch();
    }
};

int test(Base* x) {
    auto f = x->f_dispatch();
    int ret = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < (1<<30); ++i) { ret = f(ret); }
    return ret;
}
```

The idea is that the lambda inside `std::function` will encapsulate a fully-devirtualized path. So you only are left with one virtual call (the one in `std::function` itself).

---

Another solution, less generic but *much* more amenable to optimizations, is to turn things around: instead of invoking a virtual function in a loop, let the virtual function do the loop (at its innermost level).

This has the advantage, much as in the previous solution, of only resolving the virtual call chain once; however on top it also means that the entire loop inside the finally invoked function can be vectorized/optimized/...

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual int f(int i)                    { return i+1; }

    virtual int f_loop(int n) { 
        int ret = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { ret = this->Base::f(i); }
        return ret;
    }
};

class Derived: public Base {
    Base* another;
public:
    Derived(Base* a): another(a) { }
    int f(int i) override { return another->f(i); }

    int f_loop(int n) override { return another->f_loop(n); }
};

int test(Base* x) {
    return x->f_loop(1<<30);
}
```

This *really* optimizes well, as demonstrated by the LLVM IR (where the entire loop + virtual dispatch + ... has been optimized out):

```
; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind uwtable
define i32 @main() #1 personality i8* bitcast (i32 (...)* @__gxx_personality_v0 to i8*) {
_Z4testP4Base.exit:
  %0 = tail call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* nonnull getelementptr inbounds ([10 x i8], [10 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0), i32 1073741824)
  ret i32 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, two really useful hints.

Comment: Unfortunately, in your first solution, I need to pay a quite high price: inline functions will get outline. (I suppose I can't avoid this?) The other solution is quite specific, but great where applicable.  I'll keep both option in mind...

Comment: @ralfg: virtual call (unless de-virtualized) and inline calls are mutually exclusive. If you measure a performance issue because of virtual calls, it means they were not inlined, and in this situation switching to the first solution is *always* a performance win :)

Answer (score 0):

By analyzing the scenario we have a `virtual` method which invokes another `virtual` method which could keep invoking `virtual` methods on different classes.

This is a strong level of indirection as you have something like `f(f2(f3(f4(x))))` and the behavior of each function is not decided at compile-time but at runtime time through a vtable.

In addition you don't want to use templates (what kind of requirement is this? why do you have such a requirement?).

It sounds like an XY problem, what are you trying to achieve exactly? If you are trying to compute a value through successive applications of a generic function which could be anything at runtime it's clear that this comes with a cost.

If the problem is the amount of `virtual` calls done, then the only thing you can try is to minimize the amount, especially because a `virtual` doesn't have much overhead per se. You could try to redesign the structure such that you process all the data at once, eg:

```
virtual void foo(vector<int>& data) {
  std::transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), [] (int value) { return value + 1; });
  other->foo(data);
}
```

This would minimize the amount of virtual calls to one per layer but of course you will incur in other costs. This could prove better in your specific case if you are going to store computed values somewhere in any case, which may or may not be true and it's not clear since **you didn't give any specification of the problem**.

Comment: XY problem! Would it be possible to get the actual function address once and for all if we know that we're going to call the method from this object more than once? For example a virtual function returning the actual adress of the function to call a million times.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre isnt that covered by branch prediction already?

Comment: I'm in a quandary. On one hand I want to up vote this because these are good questions. On the other hand I feel obliged to flag it because it's not actually an answer.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to cache the whole serie of function addresses once before invoking the whole chain (but I'm not sure that this will guarantee any performance benefit), or also have something like `virtual void f(vector<int>& dataSet)` so that you call them once by passing all the data instead that a call for each required computation.

Comment: @Jack: Im not in general against templates. Just static (template) polymorphism is no choice, as recursion depth is not known.
My question is: Can I somhow avoid the call of a chain Derived::f(Derived::f(Derived::f(Base::f(x)))), as it would occur in my example?

Comment: Another try to clarify my question: You give a nice suggestion to reduce  the number of virtual function calls per layer. However, my code here is only a minimalistic code example. The number of calls per layer seems not reducable in my real case. Instead, I want to reduce the number of calls "vertically", i.e. skip the trivial layers for each virtual function.

Comment: What do you mean by trivial call?